# Использование MyCaffe

Tags: нейронные-сети, cuda, nvidia

В [описании](https://github.com/MyCaffe/MyCaffe) указано, что MyCaffe требует установленного инструментария CUDA 11.8.0 (или 11.7.1) и набор библиотек cuDnn 8.7.0 (или 8.5.0 соответственно). Но CUDA предназначен, как я понимаю, для компьютеров оснащённых определёнными видеокартами NVIDIA. Возможно ли выполнять обучение на мощностях процессора или обязательно нужен CUDA?

Comment: Судя по `Supported Development Environments`  из репы гитовой ПО жестко требует `Cuda`. Вы можете найти форк под процессор или переписать сами :D

Comment: В оригинальном CAFFE можно выбирать какое устройство использовать для обучения: CPU или GPU. Какой смысл в MyCaffe если его могут использовать только разработчики, у которых на рабочем компьютере видеокарта NVIDIA. Форк под процессор вряд ли существует. Переписывать самому - проще использовать обычный CAFFE. Бредово же сделано или я что то не так понимаю?